# Sharing data between URLs in plotly-dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to share data between URLS but the hidden div is not updated as parameter in the callback function, although it is clearly updated in the page.

Minimal example for reproduction:

Code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[])

layout = [dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False)]
layout += [html.Div(id='page-content')]
layout += [html.Div(children="default",
                     id='cache', style={"display": "none"})]
app.layout = html.Div(layout)


@app.callback(
       [Output('page-content', 'children'),
        Output('cache', "children")],
       [Input('url', 'pathname')],
       [State('cache', 'children')],
       )
def route(pathname, data):
    print(data)
    if "/2/" in pathname:
        return html.A(html.H2("1"), href="/1/"), dash.no_update
    elif pathname == "/1/":
        return html.A(html.H2("2"), href="/2/"), "1"
    else:
        return html.A(html.H2("2"), href="/2/"), "1"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Console output (after switching pages a couple of times):

```
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 * Serving Flask app "app2" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
default
default
default
default
default
default
default
default
default
default
default
default
default
default
```

Chrome Screenshot:

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

In my actual application page "2" queries data from a database and I want to use that data in page "1" to minimize queries.

I assume there is a timing problem somehow, but I don't get why the default value is set again after it had been overridden.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround with Stores:
Just replace the hidden div with a dcc.Store with a storage_type session or local

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[])

layout = [dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False)]
layout += [html.Div(id='page-content')]
layout += [dcc.Store(id='cache', storage_type='session')]
app.layout = html.Div(layout)


@app.callback(
       [Output('page-content', 'children'),
        Output('cache', "data")],
       [Input('url', 'pathname')],
       [State('cache', 'data')],
       )
def route(pathname, data):
    print(data)
    if "/2/" in pathname:
        return html.A(html.H2("1"), href="/1/"), dash.no_update
    elif pathname == "/1/":
        return html.A(html.H2("2"), href="/2/"), "1"
    else:
        return html.A(html.H2("2"), href="/2/"), "1"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```